# How to catch key events while soft keyboard is open android?

Tags: java, android, events, keyboard, key

I know how to catch key events in my activity by overriding

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

The problem is when the soft keyboard is open this method is not even called...
any way to catch the event anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when we speak about soft keyboard it's means that no so easy to use it. By the way methods that relate to soft keyboard take no expected result. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    //do something
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The workaround that I've found is using of TextWatcher. Use this code for your application

```
YourEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YourEdit);         
YourEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
        public void  afterTextChanged (Editable s)
        { 
            //checking of TextWatcher functionality
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "afterTextChanged", 3).show();    
            //do something
        } 

        public void  beforeTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        { 
            //checking of TextWatcher functionality
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "beforeTextChanged", 3).show();    
            //do something
        } 

        public void  onTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        { 
            //checking of TextWatcher functionality
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "onTextChanged", 3).show();    
            //do something
        }
});
```

These methods are called sequentially: beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged and afterTextChanged. You can catch any phase of text changing.
Good luck!