# catching the "OK" button vs pressing "round-arrow" on EditText in Android

Tags: android, keyevent

I have an EditText with      `android:inputType="phone"` keybord. There is an `"OK"` on this keyboard. I like to catch pressing this OK btn. However I don't know the key event. I would like to use code like this:

```
 setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
            {
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
                {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        switch (keyCode)
                        {
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            case KeyEvent.?????????? <- this one please

                                return true;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I hope the code is different from pressing the "round-arrow"!

I checked all the key events in the docs but could not find anything.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be done, but take a look at [How to catch key events while soft keyboard is open android?][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883334/how-to-catch-key-events-while-soft-keyboard-is-open-android

Comment: You could use a simple `System.out.println` on the event's keyCode, and look in the docs for it's relative constant.

Comment: If I just put a Log there I get back 66, does that mean it is 66 on all Android phones or could it differ? Ps Draiken, I am not sure what you mean with "relative constant"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'OK' button is usually associated with finishing the input, and is different from the others. Use `setOnEditorActionListener` to catch it:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener()
    {
      public boolean onEditorAction( TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event )
      {
        // Do what you want to do here
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but for some reason nothing works anymore. ie the other listeners do not react and the setOnEditorActionListener does not seem to catch anything (it does not even print a Log.i in the body)