# Dynamic value passing from numeric EditText to String in same Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is a 2 part question. Firstable, I have this `EditText` which is strictly set that user can put numbers only by `android:inputType="number"`. Like:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit_A1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/zeroes" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/act_string"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="000," />
```

What kind of output do I get from it? Is it normal `String` or `Integer`?

Secondly, I would like to set the `TextView` (code above) this way that when I input the number to the `EditText` and hit `OK` button from the appeared numpad, the number will immediately appear in the `TextView`. Both `EditText` and `TextView` are in the same activity. I have the following code:

```
public static class MainSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        EditText mAcu1ET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_A1);
        TextView mAcu1TV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.act1);

        //????

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

to create the view. What kind of `onClickListener` should I implement so my `TextView` would change its value on `OK` button click from the `EditText` numpad? Still learning, go easy on me.

Title of the topic might be confusing, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions worked. I found out the solution here: [catching the "OK" button vs pressing "round-arrow" on EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756499/catching-the-ok-button-vs-pressing-round-arrow-on-edittext-in-android)

To sum up, my code would look like this:

```
public static class MainSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText mAcu1ET;
    private TextView mAcu1TV;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

            mAcu1ET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_A1);
            mAcu1TV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.act1);

            mAcu1ET.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction( TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event ) {   
                        mAcu1TV.setText(mAcu1ET.getText().toString());
                     return false;
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for contributing! Raghandunan somehow led me to it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got it, you want to write a number, press OK and see that number in both fields?

Comment: public void setNumber(View view){
     mAcu1TV.setText(mAcu1ET.getText().toString);
}
I'm guessing it would be something like that

EDIT: Sorry I couldn't set the code type text

Answer (score 0):

Edit text will always give you string but you can type cast it into number.

```
mAcu1ET.getText().toString();
```

Code:

```
public static class MainSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText mAcu1ET;
    TextView mAcu1TV;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        mAcu1ET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_A1);
        mAcu1TV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.act1);

            mAcu1ET.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg1==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER){

                                 mAcu1ET.setText(mAcu1TV.getText().toString());
                             }
            return false;
        }
    });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not refer to `findViewById(R.id.ok)` as I have no such button in my layout.

Comment: check my edited ans. took the idea from Raghunandan as i did't get the que before

Answer (score 0):

On button click:

```
String set = youreditText.getText().toString();
yourtextView.setText(set);
```

EditText, even if the `inputType` is in number, will only give you the keyboard configuration for number. You will always need to `getText().toString()` to get the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnKeyListener`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

```
mAcu1ETt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
            /* do something */ 
        }
    }
 });
```